# Dynamic height with infinite scroll (react-virtualized)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using 'react-virtualized' to render an infinite scrolling list.

However, I am having trouble rendering the `rowHeight` dynamically. I made an attempt, but it only is relevent for desktop, and feels wrong.

I tried following the examples, but had no success.

What is the correct way to calculate the true row height?

It should be responsive to mobile.

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ADARgvlxB

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
        <List
          height={600}
          width={width}
          rowCount={foo.length}
          rowHeight={({ index }) => {
            const x = foo[index];
            if (x.name.length < 10) { return 20; } 
            else if (x.name.length > 9) { return 40;}
          }}
          rowRenderer={({ index, style }) => {
            const x = foo[index];
            return (
              <div key={index} style={style}>
                {x.name}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        />
        )}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct way to calculate the true row height?

This is what the react-virtualized [`CellMeasurer` component](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) is for. You can see a [demo of it measuring dynamic heights here](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/CellMeasurer). The source code for the demo are the [`*.example.js` files here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/tree/master/source/CellMeasurer).

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried following their example but had no success. Images have set height (px) whereas I will be accounting for text.

Comment: The Code Sandbox you linked to doesn't seem to be following the example because it doesn't use `CellMeasurer`. Check out the links I provided above again.